# Broadcast IP Canon xf200 Camera using RTSP

Tags: streaming, rtsp, rtp, ip-camera

I am trying to make a publicly viewable stream using an IP camera, (ideally to embed in a webpage) in this particular case it's a Canon xf200.

I've been able to locally set up the camera to stream across my network using the RTP transport protocol, and can view the stream just fine using VLC -> view network stream.

What I'm not able to get hold of is the RTSP url, there's no documentation from the manufacturer about how this is formatted.

As far as i'm aware, I need the RTSP url to publicly broadcast the stream using program such as xsplit/wirecast broadcasters.

The stream details (from VLC) are:

Stream 0

Type: Video
Original ID: 4113
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)
Resolution: 640x386
Display resolution: 640x360
Frame Rate: 25
Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Stream 1
Type: Audio
Original ID: 4352
Codec: MPEG AAC AUDIO (mp4a)
Channels: Stereo
Sample Rate: 48000 Hz

What would be the best way to get hold of the RTSP URL - and is this the best route to go down in order to publicly broadcast?

Comment: I am working on this as well. marys62, I've tried your solution without success, but I'm trying to contact Canon for clarification. What I can say is the following: Remember to turn off networking to make changes to your IP streaming settings, and to wait until the IP streaming icon goes completely white before testing.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found the solution, which is :

- set the camera to stream with the RTP protocol to the ip address and to the port of the XF200 (I set 1024); this mean that the stream will be a unicast one, i.e. destined only to the XF200
- inside VLC, choose :
  Protocol: RTP
  Mode: Unicast 
  Address: Port 1024

This generates a url like rtp://@:1024
It worked for me after I replaced the @ by the ip address of my machine on the network, either when using a LAN (Ethernet) connection or my home wifi router.

I tried the same solution with "Cameleon" and it worked also.

I am now looking for the same thing as you, i.e. how to reroute the signal with VLC to skype or another destination.

I will keep you posted if I succeed.